# R fill datas.frame with random values without a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I need to know something. I want to fill a data.frame D with values.
This should be done with dbeta so Im doing something like this

```
d[1:10,1:10] <- 0.01 + (1-0.01)*rbeta(1,shape1=1,shape2=2)
```

However this generates the same value for all entries. Is there a way
to achieve this without a loop?

Thanks
R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do :

```
d[1:10,1:10] <- 0.01 + (1-0.01)*rbeta(100, shape1=1,shape2=2)
```

Comment: Really?  14 seconds ahead of me!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try  `rbeta(100,...)`  to create 100 samples in one swell foop.